# Issue with updating a document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm finding problem in updating the documents which are inserted into the DB.
I have created a web page where I can insert the document into the DB and retrieve and display it on the same page. However, I'm not able to update the existing document.

When I try update the document using the `objectID`, the data is not getting updated.

I would like help or suggestions on what to do.

FYI: the DB I have used here is `'iot'` and the collection is : `'metadata'`

I'm  a beginner in JS and MongoDB.
I would kindly need some help with this.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var assert = require('assert');
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(url);
const dbName = 'iot';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next){
  var resultArray = [];
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    var cursor = db.collection('metadata').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc, err) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      resultArray.push(doc);
    }, function(){
      client.close();
      res.render('index', {items: resultArray});
    });
  });
});

router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
  var item = {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.body.author
  }
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    db.collection('metadata').insertOne(item, function(err, result){
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log('Item inserted');
      client.close();
    });
  });
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/update', function(req, res, next) {
  var item = {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.body.author
  };
  var id = req.body.id;

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    db.collection('metadata').updateOne({"_id": objectId(id)}, {$set: item}, function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log('Item updated');
     db.close();
    });
  });
  ///res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.body.id;

  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('metadata').deleteOne({"_id": objectId(id)}, function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log('Item deleted');
      db.close();
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
<h1>HOME DASHBOARD </h1>
<section class="insert">
    <h3>Insert Data</h3>
    <form action="/insert" method="post">
        <div class="input">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="content">Content</label>
            <input type="text" id="content" name="content">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">INSERT</button>
    </form>
</section>
<section class="get">
    <h3>Get Data</h3>
 <a href="/get-data">LOAD DATA</a>
    <div class="gfg">
    <div>
        {{# each items }}
            <article class="item">
                <div>Title: {{ this.title }}</div>
                <div>Content: {{ this.content }}</div>
                <div>Author: {{ this.author }}</div>
                <div>ID: {{ this._id }}</div>
            </article>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="update">
    <h3>Update Data</h3>
    <form action="/update" method="post">
        <div class="input">
            <label for="id">ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="content">Content</label>
            <input type="text" id="content" name="content">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
    </form>
</section>
</section>
<section class="delete">
    <h3>Delete Data</h3>
    <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <div class="input">
            <label for="id">ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">DELETE</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Updated the question title to make it clear.
Edited the question body to clarify the issue being experienced

Answer (score 0):

try importing the ObjectID , i don't see it there

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true});


var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

// In your request
{ "_id": ObjectID(req.body.id)}, // Filter

//in your code 
client.connect(function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    db.collection('metadata').updateOne({ "_id": ObjectID(req.body.id)}, {$set: item}, function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log('Item updated');
     db.close();
    });
  });
```

Comment: thank you @ABDELJALIL AIT ETALEB
it works somewhat,but throws error and crashes.
i need to start the server again to view the updated data.
can you pls help me out in this

Comment: @sanjay and replace the MongoClient used in the routes with the constante "client" that u initiated from the MongoClient class  you use it to connect without giving it url everytime